# Angular callback or promise to trap return vale

Tags: angularjs, callback, angular-promise

I am racking my brain trying to get this to work correctly. I have tried callbacks and promises and am open to both.  I modeled my code using the Mean Stack as laid out by Joe Eames in a Pluralsight class.  I am still learning so please excuse my terminology if incorrect but here is how this works with code as illustrated below.

My interface calls flQuestionCrudCtrl.createQuestion that calls flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion that calls flQuestion.Create.  flQuestion.Create makes an http post request to a server that writes to a mongodb collection.  Everything seems to work fine, data is written to the database and I can see the return value in flQuestionCrud per console logs. When I try to read the “data” return parameter in flQuestionCrudCtrl I get, “Error: data is undefined”.   I have tried every combination of callback and promise but cannot get it to work.  Can you see what I am doing wrong?

```
  angular.module('app').controller( 'flQuestionCrudCtrl',function(flConstructDataService, flQuestionDataService, flQuestionCrud, flCachedReferenceData,flCachedQuestions, flAnswer, $scope, $location, $q, flIdentity, flNotifier,$timeout, $state) {


$scope.createQuestion = function() {

function doWorkAsync() {
    return $timeout(flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion(currentQuestionData), 10);
}

doWorkAsync()
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success " + data);
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success Statement " + data.statement);
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success Question id " + data._id);
        currentQuestionData._id = data._id;
        flQuestionDataService.setNewQuestionId(data._id);
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - currentQuestionData._id " + currentQuestionData._id);
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - flQuestionDataService.getNewQuestionId() " + flQuestionDataService.getNewQuestionId());
        $state.go('questionUpdate');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Error " + err);
        $state.go('questionCreate');
    })
    .finally();
};

}


angular.module('app').factory('flQuestionCrud',function($http, $q, $state, $timeout, flQuestion ){
    return {
        createNewQuestion: function(newQuestionData) {
            console.log("Before - flQuestion.create");

        function createQuestionDataAsync(questionData) {
            console.log("flQuestionCrud - Before Call to create ")
            var returnData;
            flQuestion.create(questionData, function(data) {
                console.log("flQuestionCrud - After Call to create ")
                if (!data){
                    return Error("Error Creating Data");
                    //return null;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success " + data);
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success Statement " + data.statement);
                    console.log("flQuestionCrud - Try Section - Success Question id " + data._id);
                }
                return data;
            });
        }

        createQuestionDataAsync(newQuestionData); 
    },
```

Comment: Are you getting the 'undefined' error when your trying to log the data in the 'then' part of your doWorkAsync function?

Comment: Yes, line 198 is the second log statement in the then where I try to display the statement.  the first log statement displays undefined. Below is the output from the first log statement and then the error.          Before - flQuestion.create flQuestionCrud.js:4:13
flQuestionCrud - Before Call to create  flQuestionCrud.js:46:17
flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success undefined flQuestionCrudCtrl.js:197:17
Error: data is undefined
$scope.createQuestion/<@http://localhost:3030/app/questions/flQuestionCrudCtrl.js:198:17
processQueue@http://localhost:3030/vendor/angular/angular.js:14792:28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion()` method should return the promise resolved with `data`:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('flQuestionCrud', function($http, $q, $state, $timeout, flQuestion ){
        return {
            createNewQuestion: function(newQuestionData) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                flQuestion.create(questionData, function(data) {
                    if (data){
                        // whatever we resolve the promise with will be passed 
                        // to the `then` handler in the controller
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        deferred.reject("Error Creating Data");
                    }
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Note, we're explicitly creating the promise and resolve or reject it depending on what `flQuestion.create()` returns.

This way you'll be able to access the `data` in your controller the way you do it:

```
flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion(currentQuestionData)
    .then(function(data) {
        // work with data here
    });
```

or

```
doWorkAsync()
    .then(function(data) {
        // work with data here
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you , thank you.  Embarrassing to say how long I have tried to get this to work.  In all the reading and examples promises looked like magic and your solution showed that it is a bit of the behind the scenes magic I will just need to accept.  BTW, what I had in the controller did not work, not sure why, but what you suggested worked fine.  Really appreciate you helping with this.  I will be reaching out more often.

Comment: @j-terranova, you're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, you should mark it as "accepted".